# I can't able to parse a localStorage sting into JSON object

Tags: javascript

```html
let arr = {};
 
arr['0'] = '5';
arr['1'] = '4';
 
localStorage.setItem('arr', arr);
val = localStorage.getItem('arr');
console.log(val);
```

If I put val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'));, it throws an error stating that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()
at app.js:230.

arr is an object, when I stored it to localStorage, it got stored as string of [object object], how can i access the individual value of arr from localStorage.

Comment: it would make sense to actually see the [documentation about localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)... so you can find that you can only store strings ... and `['5','4'].toString()` is in fact `"5","4"` and not a valid entry to use with `JSON.parse()` - bottom line, please start looking at the docs when things don't make sense to you ... you can go a long way with the simple things 

Answer (score 2):

Use this while storing:

```
localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

while getting:

```
let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` can only store strings, so you need to `JSON.stringify` when `setItem` and `JSON.parse` when `getItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
let arr = {};

arr['0'] = '5';
arr['1'] = '4';

localStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(arr));

val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'));

console.log(val);
```